# Prompting user to input line numbers for copying with sed

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I've trying to find a way to ask a user to enter line numbers that he desires to be copied to a new file with sed but I can't seem to manage it.
I can do it for a single line or range but I want multiple specific lines chosen by the user.
Is that possible?

This has worked for me for a single line so far.

```
read lineNr  
sed -n ""$lineNr""p file1 > file2
```

How do I do it for multiple lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read multiple line numbers into an array and then use parameter expansion to turn that array into a sed command:

```
read -a arr -p "Enter line numbers: "
sed -n "${arr[*]/%/p;}" infile
```

The `read` command reads space separated numbers into the array `arr`. The second command then uses parameter expansion:

- `"${arr[*]}"` on its own returns a single string with all the array elements, like `1 3 5`.
- The `/%/p;` part is a substitution: it says "replace at the end of each array element (`/%`) nothing with `p;`", which effectively appends `p;` to each array element:

  ```
  $ arr=(1 3 5 7)
  $ echo "${arr[*]/%/p;}"
  1p; 3p; 5p; 7p;
  ```

So when entering a bunch of line numbers, the sed command prints only the corresponding lines.

By the way, the quotes in your command don't do anything, other than separating the `lineNr` variable name from `p`. Did you mean something like

```
sed -n "${lineNr}p"
```

maybe?